# jProfiler timings on the Call Tree with Thread Status "All States"

Tags: jprofiler

The time for e.g. 187 seconds displayed against a URL invocation is the actual wall clock time right?( Thread Status: All States).

Now, when I look at Method Statistics view , I could see the same time for 187 seconds against the URL. However, I see other methods in the execution path takes more than 187 seconds. IS this because both of these are from different perspectives?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question without more context. How do you limit the data in the method statistics view to a single URL invocation?

Comment: Sure, I start recording when I hit a button(Form submit) of a page and then stop the recording when the response page gets rendered. Thanks!

Comment: OK, but a lot of other things can happen at the same time. Maybe you can add some screen shots.

Comment: What other methods do you see taking more than the HTTP request? There are always idle worker threads on the server, and you should expect the "idle" methods in those threads to take as long as recording is enabled.